# Видимость элементов после 3d-поворота

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Просьба объяснить и дать совет как исправить поведение элементов разметки.

Почему кнопка на лицевой стороне после поворота остается видимой и кликабельной?

[ссылка](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzGbBb)

```js
document.getElementById('main-request').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.flip-card').classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
```

```css
.mycolor {
  background-color: #4d367b;
}

.w-30 {
  width: 30% !important;
}

.ask-btn,
.navbar-brand,
.nav-link {
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.ask-btn:hover {
  background-color: #3DCC3C;
}

.flip-card-scene {
  margin-top: 20px;
  perspective: 2500px;
  height: 120px;
}

.flip-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-front {}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container content-wrap">
  <div class="flip-card-scene">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="card-face card-front">
        <h4 class="text-center my-3 text-secondary" id="main-title">Front Title</h4>
        <!-- main title -->
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn ask-btn text-white mycolor w-30" id="main-request">Action</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back">
        <h4 class="text-center my-3 text-secondary">Back Title</h4>
        <!-- main title -->
        <div class="row" id="cart-cont2">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn text-white w-25">Back</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: видимо дело в бутстрапе

Comment: Отключи `bootstrap` и увидишь, что `backface-visibility: hidden;` работает.. Видать у `bootstrap` есть свое правило  `backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: видимо вопрос трогает самые глубокие кишки css...
похоже на [решение](https://nicolaskadis.info/projects/pure-css-flip-cards-using-bootstrap-4-and-css-grid-no-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение

```js
document.getElementById('main-request').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.flip-card').classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
```

```css
.mycolor {
  background-color: #4d367b;
}

.w-30 {
  width: 30% !important;
}

.ask-btn
 {
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.ask-btn:hover {
  background-color: #3DCC3C;
}

.flip-card-scene {
  margin-top: 20px;
  perspective: 2500px;
  height: 120px;
}

.flip-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.flip-card div {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-front {}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container content-wrap">
  <div class="flip-card-scene">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="card-face card-front">
        <h4 class="text-center my-3 text-secondary" id="main-title">Front Title</h4>
        <!-- main title -->
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn ask-btn text-white mycolor w-30" id="main-request">Action</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back">
        <h4 class="text-center my-3 text-secondary">Back Title</h4>
        <!-- main title -->
        <div class="row" id="cart-cont2">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn text-white w-25">Back</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

для мобильных браузеров обязательно оставлять свойства -webkit